# preg_match not between specific tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have template engine. when matching {if}...{/if} block, content splitting by {else|elif} condition.

But when content have nested {if}...{/if} block, {else|elif} condition algorithm matching wrong else or elif tags.

maybe i have a content like this;

[example content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpOnl.png)

black line should selectable but red line unselectable.

this is my old matching pattern but it's not working properly

```
/{(else|elif)[\s]*(.*?)[\s]*}/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all("/\{\/if}(.*?)\{if \$test3 \}/ms", $input_lines, $output_array);
Echo $output_array[1];
```

See it in action http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fhf

(You need to push the preg_match_all-button for it to work)

Comment: yes this working but not properly. For example when content "abc {else} xyz" regex couldnt match. So i think i need a "(?!)" modifier or something like this.

Comment: Sorry but still not working. i need pattern like this.
(not between{if}) {(else|elif).....} (not between{/if})
But i cant write proper regex

Comment: @redfox9999 I'm having problems understanding what you are looking for. If the code above was correct for the example you gave above. Then give one more example what you are looking for. Because your text does not match your example in my opinion. You want to match between if and /if but give an match example between /if and if.

Comment: It's still very muddy... Sorry. I suggest you drop the preg_match idea and try to loop through the text and using strpos to find out if the correct tag is found. Then just keep looping with a inner loop and saving the "data" to an array till you find the end tag.